# Spring context and application initiation

Tags: spring, autowired, spring-boot

I am writing an app based on Spring Boot. I am trying to understand the difference and implications between doing either of the following:

```
AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppContext.class);
```

or

```
SpringApplication.run(MySpringConfiguration.class, args);
```

Particularly I am interested in following implications:

1. Autowiring. When I manually get context the concrete objects inside
   my class don't get autowired even though I can see them in the
   context, when debugging.
2. Testing. Which way is easier to test with?

Answer (score 1):

Autowiring and testing should be nearly identical in both cases (the `SpringApplication` has a companion test annotation `@SpringApplicationContext` but that's the only main difference). The difference is in the features provided by `SpringApplication` on top of the vanilla application context (embedded servlet container, logging initialization, external config file parsing, etc.).

Comment: Just to double check - stuff will not be "autowired" into a class in which I just do "new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(..)". That's what I am seeing at least.

Comment: Autowiring should work by default if you use `@Configuration` in any form. Maybe you didn't do that?